# Is Kinana relevant in the manga?

Tags: fairy-tail

I may not remember very well, but I think it was after the Edoras Arc that Kinana makes her first appearance **in the anime** as a maid within the guild.

We know for a fact that she was previously Cubelios, Oracion Seis Cobra's partner.

Her only relevance as Kinana in the anime was to **hear** him at the end of the filler arc (anime only) including the "New Oracion Seis" and I think she reappeared again at the end of the Dragon King's Festival for the same purpose (poor girl).

And as I don't remember very well how things turned out in the manga at the end of that same arc, my question is

**Did she serve any purpose at all in the manga as Kinana?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply no. You don't even see her in fights. Such a shame really.

Comment: at least, she's in good hands